# What's the point with "opened" and "closed" notebooks in OneNote app?

Tags: 8.0, onenote

In the Windows Phone 8 the new OneNote app shows a list  of notebooks categorized by "opened" and "closed".

You can choose one opened and close it. To open a closed one just tap like you does with opened.

So why does this categorization exists?

Answer (score 4):

An Open notebook allows for syncing to keep everything up to date on the device. If you "close" the notebook, then changes to that notebook won't take effect on your phone until you open it again.

Comment: But if I leave it "open" it only sync when I tap it like the one closed.